# What's the difference in c++ between new int and new (int)?

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization

what's the difference between

```
int * num = new (int);
```

and

```
int * num = new int;
```

?

Is there a difference at all?

**EDIT**
thx all. ... which one is the *most correct* answer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There isn't a difference in the context of your example (using an *int* type). 
However, there is a difference if you need to create objects of compound types, where you need to use parenthesized version. i.e:

```
int (**fn_ptr_ok) ()  = new (int (*[10]) ()); // OK
int (**fn_ptr_err) ()  = new int (*[10]) (); // error
```

Comment: That is the array of 10 pointers to functions (that return int and take no arguments). Check this out: http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html

Answer (score 10):

For this particular case, no difference at all. Both are same. Just that first syntax is rarely used, maybe because it looks inconvenient and cryptic, and requires more typing!

Answer (score 6):

There's another difference when you want to create a dynamic array

```
int n = 2;
int *p = new int[n]; // valid
int *q = new (int[n]); // invalid
```

The parenthesized version requires a constant size.

Comment: For the second one, you still need to use `delete[]`, yes?

Comment: @Charles yes you need to use `delete[]`.

Comment: so if `n` is constant, second one is equal to allocating space for ONE object(NOT n), which has exactly same type as `int arr[n]`? Right?

Comment: @Ashot, second one, if `n` is constant, is exactly equivalent to first. It just requires `n` to be constant. In both cases one object (an array object) is created, which contains `n` objects. The parentheses don't mean something different in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

In this question's case, the meanings of these two `new`s are identical.
Grammatically, the operand of the former form `new ()` is type-id,
and the operand of the latter is new-type-id.
As for new-type-id, if `(....)` appears at the back of the operand, it is
interpreted as the argument list of the constructor.
That is, If we write `new int(1)`, the `int` is initialized to 1.
On the other hand, as for type-id, if `(....)` appears, it is a part of the type.
For example, when we `new` a pointer to a function, we have to use
`new( type-id )` form.
For example, as `new( int(*)() )`.

Comment: I think I understood what you were trying to say. I am rather proud of my mind reading skills.

Answer (score 2):

(Not really an answer, but I can't put this into a comment)

Its even more complicated because of "placement new":
http://codepad.org/pPKt31HZ

```
#include <stdio.h>

void* operator new( size_t N, int x ) {
  return new char[N];
}

int main( void ) {
  int x = int();
  int* a = new( int() ) int;
}
```

Here its interesting that gcc accepts this, but not MS/Intel.